# cron Job Won't Run on R Scripts on Google Compute Engine

Tags: cron, google-compute-engine, rstudio-server

Following these instructions I got R-Studio Server running on a Google Compute Instance: http://code.markedmondson.me/launch-rstudio-server-google-cloud-in-two-lines-r/

When I open a terminal from this RStudio-Server I note that man, ps, vi, cron are all absent.

```
bash: ps: command not found
```

My goal is to have a simple cron job periodically run an R-Script.
I manually installed cron with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cron
```

Still, I can't get cron to run this test:

```
cmd <- cron_rscript("/home/law9723/now_to_file.R")
cron_add(cmd, frequency = "*/1 * * * *", id = "now_to_file", description = "Write now to file every minute")
```

-Clearly Confused

Comment: I understand that you're trying to add a cron job by using the R Interface with Google Compute Engine, by running cron_add.
Are you getting an error message? If so could you post it here for more context? Thanks.

Comment: Hi. There was no error message. I got things to work eventually using these instructions to start a vm:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got things to work eventually by using these very helpful instructions: https://yuhuisdatascienceblog.blogspot.ca/2017/07/setting-up-r-studio-server-on-google.html

Using absolute path names with everything associated with cron is sage advice.

I think when I created a vm with this command the sandbox that Rstudio-server lives in is very minimal. Hence, no vi, man, cron, ps...

```
gce_vm(template = "rstudio",
             name = "my-rstudio",
             username = "mark", password = "mark1234",
             predefined_type = "n1-highmem-2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had success using the rstudio addin. A reference is 
http://www.bnosac.be/index.php/blog/51-new-rstudio-add-in-to-schedule-r-scripts.

I am also under the impression that you have to start cron with

```
sudo cron start
```

As in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cronR/README.html.

I install the packages shinyFiles, miniUI and cronR when I first get into the Rstudio on GCE after using googleComputeEngineR locally like you. Then "Schedule R scripts on Linux/Unix" will appear in the add-in list.